# the order of assigning values

Tags: c++

I am looking for some explanations regarding the behavior of the following code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = (4,5,6);
cout<<a+b;
```

Why is it that **b** takes the last value **6**?

EDIT: Sorry, I made the wrong example, thanks to all for the explaining how b gets the value 6.

Comment: And how did you get that first line to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, your code is not syntactically valid.

`2` and `3` should be declaration names. Like `c` and `d`.

To use the comma operator, you have to parenthesize `1, 2, 3`.

I will forgive you this accident and continue to explain.

If you use the comma operator, which is used as `operand1 , operand2`, it will give you the value (or lvalue) of `operand2`. So you initialize `b` to `6` (as in `(4, 5), 6`, since the comma operator is left associative).

Comment: @TamásSzelei: it's litb, he is allowed to do it :D

Comment: @Tam i'm not sure why you are offended. I could aswell have not tried to make any sense out of that line. God be with Benjamin for being a brave guy too and guess another viable meaning out of that code.

Comment: No, I'm not offended. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is not valid, however, if you move the assignment to a separate line from the declaration, it would be, and the behavior is explained as follows.  The comma operator has the lowest precedence, lower than even assignment.  So this line:

```
a = 1,2,3;
```

Is interpreted like this:

```
(a = 1),2,3;
```

While this line would be interpreted exactly as it's read:

```
b = (4,5,6);
```

The comma operator discards the result of it's left operand, so that can be simplified to this:

```
b = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this? What are you aiming to do? Variable a can only have one value at a time and you are trying to assign it sort of like an array.

You may want this:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};    
int[] b = {4,5,6};
```

But, you cant add like you want either. You would have to iterate over both arrays and add them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cout << a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Comment: Are you unaware of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)?  Or are you implying that he was actually trying to create an array, and he was just doing it wrong? (Not saying you would be wrong, that is a perfectly valid interpretation)

Comment: Yes, that is my assumption. Since there is no real purpose in using the comma operator like this.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates in order left-to-right, (it defines a sequence point) and its value is that of the right-most operand.
This explains the case of `b = (4,5,6);`

The precedence of `=` is higher than `,` so:

```
a = 1,2,3
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(a = 1), 2, 3;
```

The value of the entire expression is `3` but a is assigned `1`.

This use of comma (as an operator) is different from that within a declaration list, which is why some are saying:

```
int a = 1, 2, 3;
```

Is invalid. I'm honestly not sure myself, but the ambiguity isn't great style. The following are both different uses of comma:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3; // declaration list
```

and:

```
int a;
a = 1, 2, 3; // a is assigned 3
```

Yours is somewhere in between.